# MySQL 5.7.9 root user doesn't work on Fedora 23

Tags: mysql, fedora

I recently installed MySQL 5.7.9 on Fedora 23 and am following the steps here: http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

I'm at section 6 where I run`mysql_secure_installation`. When I do I'm getting the following error.

```
[me@dev ~]$ /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root: 
Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I left the password blank when prompted for it. It was my understanding that the root user should have no password with a fresh install of MySQL 5.7.9. I read that random passwords can be generated when `mysql_install_db` is run, but I never ran that and a `.pid` file that would help me reset the root password for MySQL doesn't exist on my hard drive (or I'm overlooking the one that I need, there are several `.pid` files but none of them look like they're used by MySQL).

I've also tried uninstalling MySQL and deleting everything under `/var/lib/mysql` then reinstalling MySQL but this doesn't help.

So the problem is that the root user either has a password I don't know about or there is something else going on that is keeping me from logging in with the root user. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: pid files don't contain passwords. they contain the process ID of the mysql daemon while it's running.

Comment: @MarcB My mistake. I must have misread the MySQL documentation.

Comment: I can confirm the reported behaviour in a clean installation of Fedora 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, documentation at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html gives the answer. The installation has a temporary root password set automatically. The password is written in a log file at '/var/log/mysqld.log'. You will be prompted to change the password after your first login.

This installation is VERY safe. It refused my new passwords several times saying that my password, which I believe is reasonably strong, "does not satisfy the current policy requirements". One has to set very strong password.